# How to get rid of wheat that is not edible?

Tags: cleaning, food

We were given a big bag of around 10kg of wheat, but we don't use that brand.  It seems like it is very bad wheat since whatever we make with it is really hard.

Is there a way to throw it away so it might be recyclable? Throwing it down the kitchen sink isn't an option because wheat mixed with water makes flour and will clog  the whole pipeline.

How do I get rid of processed wheat?

Comment: May I ask what you tried making with it? Do you have wheat (which would be the whole grains) or flour (milled to a powder) or something in between like semolina or bulgur?

Comment: Consider contacting a local food bank which might appreciate the donation.

Comment: If this is not your usual brand then it might be **plain flour**, that is, has no [self-raising agent](https://www.mamtaskitchen.com/recipe_display.php?id=13031). So one solution would be to add a raising agent. Which/how depends on the intended use, as shown here: [Types of Raising Agents](https://www.dovesfarm.co.uk/hints-tips/types-of-raising-agents).

Comment: VTC.  Without knowing what product (whole grain, meal, flour, etc.) this is impossible to answer well.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Wheat does not come in branded form, it is a grain.  Mixing wheat with water does not make flour, at best it makes wallpaper paste.  What is "processed wheat"?

Answer (score 4):

Since you know it will block the sink, presumably you have *ground* or *milled* wheat: flour.
You can use it to make

- **Play dough**. Mix 2 cups flour, 1/2 cup salt, 1 tbsp vegetable oil, and just enough water to create a clay-like consistency. *Do not eat.*
- **Glue**. Mix flour and water and remove or squash out any lumps, to the right thickness for glue.
- **Compost**. Don't throw the whole bag onto the compost heap. Sprinkle some over the top to get rid of it bit by bit.

Answer (score 2):

If it is really bad that you can’t consider for donation, use it as poultry feed. Chickens do eat a lot, so it’s not worth raising a new chicken but if you know someone who has a farm, they would love it. Pigeons love wheat. Most birds do.  You can even befriend a bird.

Comment: Good point, if it’s really grains. The phrase “processed wheat” makes it unclear and the asker hasn’t responded to questions.

Comment: Agreed, "wheat mixed with water make flour" in the Q makes no sense.

Comment: That’s so true. The question is not clear and it has been 4 days. I don’t know, but here in my place, flour doesn’t come in 10kg pack. Whole grains will be in 10kg pack. But again wheat mixed with water is still there.